# Missing request attribute 'projektId' of type String | Thymleaf Form with just a String

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Projekt where you can add workers to projects with their ids.I am using springboot, thymeleaf and a database means you give a project and a worker Id and the programm adds the worker to the project.workerlist. The Problem ist that I get this error:

```
Required request parameter 'projektId' for method parameter type String is not present
```

My HTML Form looks like this

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{neuenMitarbeiterzuProjektHinzufuegen}" method="post">
        Projekt ID: <input type="text" th:value="*{projektId}" required/><br>
        Mitarbeiter ID: <input type="text" th:value="*{mitarbeiterId}" required/><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Mitarbeiter hinzufügen"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
    </form>
```

My Post Route Handler Method looks like this

```
    @PostMapping(value="/neuenMitarbeiterzuProjektHinzufuegen")
public String neuenMitarbeiterzuProjektHinzufuegen(@RequestAttribute(value = "projektId") String projektID, @RequestAttribute(value = "mitarbeiterId") String mitarbeiterID,Model m)
{
    Optional<Projekt> projekt = projektRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(projektID));
    projektRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(projektID)).get().mitarbeiterHinzufuegen(mitarbeiterRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(mitarbeiterID)).get());
    return "redirect:Projekte";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code example I think you should be using `@RequestParam` not `@RequestAttribute`. Param is for things posted from the user (web) side and attribute you can set on the server side.

This blog has some explanation on the difference of `@RequestAttribute` https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-attribute.html